# error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value in C

Tags: c

I am writing a code where I have to add a value to an abstract data table, but I am not sure why I cannot as it shows "error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value" error.

```
int top_add(top_string *table, const char index[257], const char other[257]) {

    top_remove(&table, index);

    if (table->item_count == table->size) {
        printf("/n Table is full.");
        return -1;
    }

    /* error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value */
    table->item[table->item_count].index = index; 

    /*error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value */
    table->item[table->item_count].other = other;

    table->item_count++;

    return 1;
}
```

I did some search online, but could not find too relative solution for me.

I would really appreciate any hint on that.

UPDATE:

```
typedef struct {
    char index[257];
    char other[257];
} pair;


typedef struct {
    pair *item;
    int item_count;
    int size;
} top_string;

int top_init(top_string *table, const int size) {

    table->item = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(top_string));
    table->size = size;
    table->item_count = 0;

    if (table->item == NULL) {
        return 0; /* failed to allocate memory */
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the definition of top_string

Comment: Please show us what `table->item[table->item_count].index` and `table->item[table->item_count].other` actually are.

Comment: How do the declaration of `table->item[table->item_count].index` look like? If it's also an array then it can be assigned to, you have to copy the data through some function (like `memcpy`). Same goes for `table->item[table->item_count].other` as well.

Comment: When in doubt, you should always try to create a *minimal* test case to see if what you're doing makes sense. In your case, that would be something like `void f(const char a[10]) { char b[10]; b = a; }`. That would have made for an less noisy question, as well as giving you a narrower idea of where the problem might lie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fields `index` and `other` are arrays, you can't assign arrays. You'd have to copy them with `memcpy`.

Another option would to have `top_add` receive `pair` instead of the two separately. Then you could assign the `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problem of assigning arrays, you need to dereference the pointer table->item. And the subindex [table->item_count] must be after .index

```
((table->item)->index)[table->item_count]
```

That is a l-value

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign to arrays. You have to copy into them with strncpy, memcpy or some such.