# left operand must be l-value , C programing

Tags: c

am trying to understand how link lists work ; and on changing example code from tutor I get the 'left operand must be l-value' error ...here is my code. Any help appreciated :)

```
struct node
{
    char name[20];
    struct node *next;
};

/*Function to allocate memory and initialize node - returns pointer to node*/
struct node*mknode(char *str)
{
    struct node *np;

    np = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(np)
    {
        np->name = *str;
        np->next = NULL; /*sets the 'next' pointer to last list item to NULL*/
    }

    return np;

}

int main(void)
{

int i,menu,k=1,number;
char name[20];
char *str = name;
struct node* n;
struct node *head=NULL;


printf("Link Lists\n    1-Enter Data into lists\n   2-Display All List Items\n  3-Quit Program :(\n");

    do 
    {
        printf("\nPlease choose an option:  ");
        scanf("%d",&menu);

        switch (menu)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nPlease Enter A Number:");
                scanf("%d",&name);

                n=mknode(str); /*create new node with i as data*/

                append_node(&head,n); /*add new node to end of list*/
            break;
```

this is where i get the error

```
np->name = *str;
```

after changing the structures data type from integer to char

thanks

Comment: You're treating `np->name` as a pointer, when it's an array. You can't assign something to an array.

Comment: You can't assign directly to a character array, you need to use `strcpy` or `strncpy`

Comment: possible duplicate of [error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036324/error-c2106-left-operand-must-be-l-value-in-c)

Comment: I don't think the line `scanf("%d",&name);` does what you expect it to. It stores an `int`, but the address you've given it to store to is your `char` array, that you later use as a string.

Comment: yea that was an error in my part but I changed it to scanf("%s",&name);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C arrays aren't modifiable lvalues, i.e. **you can't assign to an array**. If I understand correctly what you are trying to do you can try:

```
strcpy(np->name, str);
```

---

If `str` isn't a trusted string (if you didn't validate it before) you could use `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: @Kevin, Ates **strncpy is not a safer version of `strcpy`**.

Comment: @Kevin Well for starters because it can leave you with a string that's not 0 terminated while giving you a sense of "oh look how great I am, I use a SAFE function".

Comment: @cnicutar I have always heard that `strncpy` was safer, would you mind briefly explaining why it isn't, or link me to some other post?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen If you pass the size of your array, that is the normal thing you'd expect you need to pass, it can leave you with a string that's not 0-terminated. Trust me: use validated strings + `strcpy` or non-validated strings and `memcpy`

Comment: @cnicutar If you're going to use `strcopy`, wouldn't you have to plan for checking the length of `str` first? How is that more convenient than just using `strncopy`?

Comment: @Kevin from the man page for strncpy:  "The stpncpy() and strncpy() functions copy at most n characters from s2
     into s1.  If s2 is less than n characters long, the remainder of s1 is
     filled with `\0' characters.  Otherwise, s1 is not terminated."  This means 1) that there is a danger of non-null termination if the string you're copying from is sufficiently lengthy and 2) waste of CPU zero-ing out *ALL* of the rest of the destination buffer if the string is shorter.  It's not a safer version of strcpy because it's really not a version of strcpy at all; it does a different thing!

Comment: @AtesGoral Using `memcpy` is just cleaner and does one and only one thing.

Comment: Sure, `strncpy(np->name,str,19);np->name[19] = 0`. Guaranteed to be null terminated and not have written way out of bounds. You're right that a "safer" function isn't foolproof (and there are a lot of fools programming c), but it *is* safer unless you go through a lot of trouble doing manual checks that you really needn't.

Comment: @Kevin We can agree to disagree :-) I'll just stick to `strcpy` + `memcpy` for the time being and to `memmove` for weirder cases.

Comment: @cnicutar thanks very much that worked, now I just need to display the contents of the structure

Comment: @cnicutar Can you please show how you would perform this particular copy operation with `memcopy`? Can it be done without the use of `strlen` somewhere?

Comment: @AtesGoral First you said `strncopy` instead of `strncpy`. Now `memcopy` instead of `memcpy`. What's up with that ? Back to your question: you do need the length somehow but that's a red herring. So does `strncpy`, only it does it implicitly.

Comment: @cnicutar My main focus wasn't on the correct spelling, sorry :)

Comment: @cnicutar It's **not** a red herring. You can't ignore the boilerplate of having to do some sort of `size_t len = strlen(str); memcpy(np->name, str, len < NAME_LEN ? len : NAME_LEN);` etc.

Comment: @AtesGoral Sure it is. In time you'll learn explicit is almost always better than implicit (and your boilerplate code is pretty bad).

Comment: @cnicutar Besides, it is generally bad idea to steer away from the commonly accepted best practices when giving advice to someone who seems to just learning stuff. If you're going to be a purist about what goes on behind the scenes and recommend the use of `memcpy`, hey, why not take it one step further and recommend using inline assembly? ;)

Comment: @AtesGoral It's not common accepted best practice. It's just peddled a lot with nobody stopping to think. I didn't recommend "purism" or "inline assembly" which you somehow pulled out of my answer + comments. I simply recommend **don't use strncpy**. Also I'll not post such "boilerplate code" because I never need it. Somehow, magically, whenever I work with strings everything has already been checked for length the second it entered my process :-)

Comment: @cnicutar In you answer, could you please provide the full boilerplate on how you would implement OP's particular problem? Your answer is incomplete without it.

Comment: 1) `strncpy` is not safe 2) an abstraction isn't implicit unless undocumented 3) speaking of `strcpy` to a beginner is just mean

Comment: Anyway, if you're worried that `strcpy` isn't safe enough for you then the correct next step is *not* to use `strncpy` instead, with code every time you use it to put in the nul terminator. The correct next step is to use (or implement if unavailable) either `strlcpy` or `strcpy_s`, *and check for unexpected string truncation*, and handle those cases.

Answer (score 1):

there are two errors in this statement

```
np->name = *str;
```

first `name` is declared as an array, you cannot change where the array is by assigning to it. instead you must copy the contents of the string to `name` using `strcpy`

```
strcpy_s( np->name, sizeof(name), str );
```

second error is that you are derefencing the string `str` in your assignment, when you derefence the string `*str` you are just copying the first character of the string, it is like writing `str[0]`

you can alternatively declare name as a char pointer instead but you then need to allocate and later free the string:

```
typedef struct node {
  char* name;
  struct node* next;
} node;
...

np->name = strdup(str); /* allocates enough space for string and copies it. */
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I am a beginner , so bear with me here. whats the difference between    strcpy_s( np->name, sizeof(name), str ); and    strcpy(np->name, str);

Comment: then wouldn't it be easier to get rid of *str and use name[20] instead as in the main program? - I don,t want to deal with memory allocation at the moment :)

Comment: @DexDave `strcpy_s` is quasi-standard. It's part of the optional Annex K *Bounds-checking interfaces* introduced in C11. It's not supported by `glibc` for example.

Comment: @cnicutar oh so strcpy is better

Comment: @DexDave Not sure if "better". But more portable, certainly. Also, whatever people tell you, don't blindly use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`.